# Is it okay to run DFS-Replication on a Windows Server 2008 Domain Controller?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

Is it okay to run DFS replication on Windows Server 2008 domain controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes... Yes it is.

Comment: I don't suppose you can point me to any documentation which will confirm this?

Comment: @Questionaire, do you have any specific reason to doubt this? BTW: There's two Ns in "Questionnaire".

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732863(WS.10).aspx. Here's an excerpt from this page:  A namespace server hosts a namespace. The namespace server can be a member server or a domain controller.

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 1):

I have set up several DFS shares that have replication between two Windows 2008 R2 Standard Edition Domain Controllers and have experienced no problems with doing so. I am using the 2008 "mode".